# Why does OS X keep forgetting my trackpad settings

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, trackpad, settings

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 on an early 2010 15" MacBook Pro. After restarting from scratch (what I don't do often usually) my trackpad is set back to "click" instead of "touch".

This started happening lately and I suspect this came with an update.

Is this a known bug and/or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Maybe OS X is trying to tell you that you shouldn't use tap-to-click because click-to-click is inherently better? (This is intended as a joke, but I do prefer click to tap.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms you describe are caused by the preference not getting saved to disk. Sometimes the cause is that there is a problem with the file permissions (as per [thaatz's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52570/732)).
Another possibility is that the preference file somehow got corrupted; if this is the case, you can move the preference file (I think the relevant one is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist`) from its location: this will cause the preference file to be recreated.
Of course this will work also for other preferences (though identifying the correct file isn't always as easy); remember to keep the file around (instead of deleting it) so you can restore it in case this fix doesn't work.

Comment: As mentioned below this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is having problems writing and saving your settings due to some sort of permission error.  Have you tried verifying and repairing disk file permissions? (use disk utility)

Comment: +1 and thanks for the tip. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: it's probably this. If repairing permissions didn't help, try moving away the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist so it gets recreated.

Comment: @Agos Is this setting about the external trackpad? My problem is about the build in one...

Comment: @Agos I tried to repair the disk file permissions and restarted but it didn't help. But your suggestion worked. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @user12999 glad it worked. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your trackpad settings are not applied in the login screen, log into an account an they will be restored to that accounts settings.

Comment: Right, it's an account setting - but it *doesn't* work after I logged in

Comment: Hmm that's strange, maybe you're experiencing some sort of bug.

Comment: Hm yeah, that was part of my questi